# Developing OEM system for S63 maps

Tags: s-57

I had a task of displaying map in s57 format. Later I found out it is encrypted in s63 format. I did not find a lot of information about this format at all. However, I found [IHO Data Protection Scheme](https://metanorma.github.io/mn-samples-iho/documents/s63/document.html), but it is hard to read and understand. To make it clear, I got the s63 map with all required licences and permissions and I need to implement the program that can decode this file and wait for lat/lon input and will display the map as needed in that location. I figured out the displaying part, but not decoding. Maybe there are ready to use solutions for such tasks or useful guide.

I am using debian-based linux, I use ogr2ogr to to get s57 map into database, I use mapnik to create PNG of map in target location when needed. All of those i am invoking from c++ code.

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: @Erik I am using debian-based linux, I use ogr2ogr to to get s57 map into database, I use mapnik to create PNG of map in target location when needed. All of those i am invoking from c++ code.

Answer (score 2):

S-63 charts are encrypted using a key (HW_ID) contained in the User Permit supplied when purchasing the charts from a data server. The HW_ID is encrypted with an M_KEY which is assigned to all OEMs registered with the IHO. In order to decrypt S-63 charts to S-57 you need to have an OEM status with the IHO and have your own M_ID and M_KEY.

If you have properly licensed S-63 charts then you must have a User Permit bound to a specific device/software.

https://metanorma.github.io/mn-samples-iho/documents/s63/document.html#toc18

You can apply for OEM status with the IHO here: https://iho.int/en/enc-data-protection

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays decrypting an S-63 chart is quite easy without having the M_KEY (for the M_ID, which is the last 4 chars of the User Permit) The only thing you need is a valid UserPermit (to get the HW_ID), and of course the cell permits.

The encryption/decryption algorythm is specified in the public "IHO Data Protection Scheme" documentation. The Blowfish algorythm which is used in the protection is very weak, it is easy to "break" (technically simply trying all the possible M_KEY-s, which is only 1048576 different values) in some seconds.
If someone is interested in a C# implementation of the algorythm or just simply wants to know the M_KEY for an M_ID or the HW_ID for a User Permit, just leave a comment.

(This does not mean that you can decrypt a chart without buying it... you still need a valid User Permit and Cell permits... but after decryption you can send the S-57 to everyone, which is not so good.)

Comment: Thanks, for help. Can you share your implementation of algorithm and how to get M_KEY for an M_ID or the HW_ID for a User Permit?

Comment: @ygroeg You can find the algorithm in this repo: https://github.com/zgabi/S63Tools
In the file called S63Tools.cs, in the method called HackUserPermit.

You can download the whole repo and execute the small application. Put the UserPermit to the first textboc, and press the Calculate button. It will show the M_KEY and HW_ID. You can also decrypt the S-63 cells with the other button. Just select the PERMIT.TXT and the ENC_ROOT (or whatever) folder which contains the encrypted cells.

Comment: ^ the cs answer above has a more complete implementation of the process, but in case anyone is interested in python I recently wrote this up to help explain the scheme with just the important bits demonstrated in python: https://heathhenley.github.io/posts/how-does-s63-enc-format-work/

Answer (score 0):

I have read more carefully the Data Protection Scheme and there is a section about [OEM and data clients processes](https://metanorma.github.io/mn-samples-iho/documents/s63/document.html#toc62) and a flowchart on what to do with examples. I will update my answer if/when i succeed with this task.

Comment: Do you have any progress how to read s63 files?

Comment: I sadly don't have anything that can help with task, the question is still open